# how-to tabbed navigation in xamarin android using mvvmcross

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, navigation, mvvmcross

I'm currently trying to implement a tabbar in xamarin android using mvvmcross
I want to add a tabbed navigation like this:
[tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO7DG.png)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:titleTextColor="#ffffffff" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        local:tabGravity="center"
        local:tabMode="scrollable" 
        />
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is? Are you looking just for the style, or are you stuck on how to implement a tabbar in Xamarin?

Comment: I am looking how to implement the tabbar in xamarin with mvvmcross!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used for tabbed navigation.
https://github.com/rrispoli/SampleTabs

It's really easy to implement